# C++11 Lambda Functions inside member methods inherit scope

Tags: c++, lambda, member-functions, c++11

I've written a function `foreach` that accepts a lambda function ala:

```
void foreach(void (*p)(pNode))
{ /* ... */ }
```

Which works as intended if I pass a lambda function from the main loop:

```
int a = 5;
env.N().foreach
(
    [&](pNode n)->void
    {
        n->tps(a); 
    }
);
```

However, if I try to call the same function from within a member method, the lambda function "inherits" the scope of the member function and generates a compiler error.  For example, if I try to include it inside the member method of class `Object` named `method()`, I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘IDSet<Node>::foreach(Object::method()::<lambda(pNode)>)’
note: candidate is: void IDSet<T>::foreach(void (*)(IDSet<T>::pT)) [with T = Node, IDSet<T>::pT = pNode]
```

I realize this is the compiler being safe, since I could include instance-specific variables inside the lambda function, in which case the lambda would need to be scoped, however I'm wondering if it's possible to make this lambda "static".

I've tried a `reinterpret_cast`, however that gives me this error:

```
error: invalid cast from type ‘Object::method()::<lambda(pNode)>’ to type ‘void (*)(pNode)’
```

Specifying `static` before `[&](pNode ...` doesn't seem like valid syntax either.

Desperately, I also tried changing `[&]` to `[=]`, `[]`, `[a]`, none of which worked.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do accomplish my goal of creating a "static" lambda function, or at any sort of lambda function that will be accepted for that matter?

Thanks!

---

**Answer:**

With help from [Cat Plus Plus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16102/cat-plus-plus), I was able to turn my incorrect code:

```
void foreach(void (*p)(pT))
{
    for(pTiter i = _map.begin(); i != _map.end(); i++)
    {
        (*p)(i->second);
    }
}
```

into fully functional code:

```
void foreach(std::function<void(pT)>(p))
{
    for(pTiter i = _map.begin(); i != _map.end(); i++)
    {
        p(i->second);
    }
}
```

that does what I was looking for perfectly.

Comment: you have missed a very important piece of information, what compiler? i assume g++ 4.5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you can not use pointers.

```
void foreach(std::function<void(pNode)>);
```

Comment: Thank you -- I'll edit my original question to reflect my final (now working!) code.

Comment: Note that according to the FDIS a captureless lambda is implicitly convertible to a function pointer. I.e., the OP's code should have been fine for a captureless (`[]`) lambda.

Comment: Well the `[]` lambda didn't work but for another reason that I wasn't really clear about, I needed to use the arguments that were passed to the member method (not member variables) inside the lambda function.  The actual call was closer to `o.method(2,5){/*...*/}`.  Thanks for the note about where it would have worked.